# Select Query not working

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have made a class of DB and use it in my forms but my select Query not working & datagridview still empty..
This is my class..

```
class ConnectDB
{
    private SqlConnection xconn;

    public ConnectDB()
    {
        xconn = new SqlConnection(new StreamReader("ConnectionDB.txt").ReadLine());
    }

    public void DMLOperations(string Query) //Execute Queries e.g Insert | Update Delete
    {
        xconn.Open();
        new SqlCommand(Query,xconn).ExecuteNonQuery();
        xconn.Close();
    }
    public DataTable GetData(string SelectQuery)
    {
        DataTable xdata = new DataTable();
        new SqlDataAdapter(SelectQuery,xconn);
        return xdata;
    }
    public void CloseDB()
    {
        xconn.Dispose();
    }
    }
```

& this my `method` which is not working

```
 private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string batch = Batch.Text;
        xDB.GetData("Select * from Students Where batch ='" + batch + "' ");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = xDB.GetData("Select * from Students Where batch ='"+batch+"' ");
        Batch.Clear();
        Batch.Focus();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to fill your table.

```
public DataTable GetData(string SelectQuery)
{
    using(var da = new SqlDataAdapter(SelectQuery,xconn))
    {
        DataTable xdata = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(xdata);
        return xdata;
    }
}
```

Comment: @DaniyalRaja if his answer helped you mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

First don't use one `Connection`, `Connection pooling` is your friend !

> Connection pooling reduces the number of times that new connections
>   must be opened. The pooler maintains ownership of the physical
>   connection. It manages connections by keeping alive a set of active
>   connections for each given connection configuration. Whenever a user
>   calls Open on a connection, the pooler looks for an available
>   connection in the pool. If a pooled connection is available, it
>   returns it to the caller instead of opening a new connection. When the
>   application calls Close on the connection, the pooler returns it to
>   the pooled set of active connections instead of closing it. Once the
>   connection is returned to the pool, it is ready to be reused on the
>   next Open call.

Here is full article about [Connection pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx)

How to build your Data Access Layer:

```
public class SqlManager
{

    public static string ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DevConnString"].ConnectionString;
        }
    }


    public static SqlConnection GetSqlConnection(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        if (cmd.Connection == null)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

            conn.Open();

            cmd.Connection = conn;

            return conn;
        }

        return cmd.Connection; 
    }

    public static int ExecuteNonQuery(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = GetSqlConnection(cmd);

        try
        {
            return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }

    public static object ExecuteScalar(SqlCommand cmd)
    {

        SqlConnection conn = GetSqlConnection(cmd);

        try
        {
            return cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }

    public static DataSet GetDataSet(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        return GetDataSet(cmd, "Table");
    }

    public static DataSet GetDataSet(SqlCommand cmd, string defaultTable)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = GetSqlConnection(cmd);

        try
        {
            DataSet resultDst = new DataSet();

            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                adapter.Fill(resultDst, defaultTable);
            }

            return resultDst;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }


    public static DataRow GetDataRow(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        return GetDataRow(cmd, "Table");
    }

    public static DataRow GetDataRow(SqlCommand cmd, string defaultTable)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = GetSqlConnection(cmd);

        try
        {
            DataSet resultDst = new DataSet();

            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                adapter.Fill(resultDst, defaultTable);
            }

            if (resultDst.Tables.Count > 0 && resultDst.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                return resultDst.Tables[0].Rows[0];
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

In this simple Data Access Layer we have 4 main Methods: `ExecuteNonQuery`, `ExecuteScallar`, `GetDataSet`, `GetDataRow`. For working with them you need to give them `SqlCommand` as parameter.

Third use `SqlCommand` parameters this will help the SQL Server to cache queries and also to prevent SqlInjection. If you are not aware what is Sql Injection, check this article: [SqlInjection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

At last how your code will look with DataAccessLayer:

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string batch = Batch.Text;

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"
                           SELECT
                               *
                           FROM
                               Student
                           WHERE
                               Batch=@Batch");


    DataSet dst = SqlManager.GetDataSet(cmd);

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dst.Tables[0];

    Batch.Clear();
    Batch.Focus();
}
```

Be aware it is not good practice to execute data access in the GUI part of your project. It is better practice to have Business Layer in which you will execute your Data Access Layer.

Comment: You `SqlManager` class has bunch of issues. Here is several: 1) Your class is stateless so it must be static. 2)`GetSqlConnection()` will throws NRE. 3) `catch{throw;}` is meaningless. ....

Comment: You are right about GetSqlConnection() I remove it, for other things I'm don't think like this.

Comment: Can you tell me the meaning of `catch{throw;}`? Also you can post your code on `http://codereview.stackexchange.com/` and read comments from other people.

Comment: Ok, about making the class static. Can you tell me at least one use case when you need to instantiate the `SqlManager` class?

Comment: Creating a static class is therefore much the same as creating a class that contains only static members and a private constructor. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx

Comment: So, what does it mean?